# Javascript 'new' keyword within function

Tags: javascript

```
var steve = function() {
  this.test = new function() {
    console.log('new thing');
  }

  this.test_not_repeating = function() {
    console.log('not repeating');
  }
}; 

steve.prototype.test = function() {
  console.log('test');
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var y = new steve();
}
```

Why does the `new` keyword force the function to be evaluated X times, where not using the `new` keyword doesn't? My rudimentary understanding of javascript is, if you do not put the function on the prototype it will be evaluated X times regardless of the `new` keyword or not.

Comment: Is that all of the code? I can see immediately that you're missing a closing brace in the constructor function. Probably off-topic from your question, but still, it stands out.

Comment: the closing bracket is in the line `steve.prototype.test = function () { console.log('test'); };` The styling is just bad

Comment: @Safari no? That's closing that anonymous function. It's still not closing the constructor (`steve`) function.

Comment: ohh true. my mistake

Comment: fixed the missing brace

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `new`?

Comment: @torazaburo Just experimenting with the langauge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is actually called as a constructor by the new operator, assigning the resulting object to `this.test`:

```
this.test = new function() {
    console.log('new thing');
}
```

This function only gets assigned to `this.test_not_repeating`, it's never called:

```
this.test_not_repeating = function() {
    console.log('new thing');
}
```

Remember that functions do not need parenthesis when called with `new`:

```
new Constructor;

// Identical to
new Constructor();
```

```
new function () {};

// Identical to
new function () {}();
```

Comment: which is better ? assigning a function without `new` or putting the function on the prototype?

Comment: @gh9: if the function doesn't need the benefit of the enclosing scope, it's usually best to put it on the prototype.